Conditional execution of commands based on grep output in shell script
I'm using a script to transcode a bunch of movies using the command line version of HandBrake. I'm using a modified a version of the script here:
https://gist.github.com/ralphcrisostomo/56fc395b1646bd55aeeb2eb442043887
The problem I have is that the transcoding hangs non-reproducibly on a small subset of movies. This is accompanied by a very specific error on stderr.
What I would like to is 1) follow stdout (but not stderr) on the screen, 2) monitor stderr for the error condition and 3) if the error condition is satisfied, kill the HandBrake process, log the offending file and move onto the next one.
At present, the transcoding command looks like this:
echo "" | HandBrakeCLI -i "$ITEM" -o "$OUTPUT" --preset="$PRESET" $OPTS 2> /dev/null

which satisfies 1).
By following the advice here:
How to grep standard error stream (stderr)?
I can successfully grep the error stream for the relevant word, e.g.
echo "" | HandBrakeCLI -i "$ITEM" -o "$OUTPUT" --preset="$PRESET" 2> >(grep -i error)

or
echo "" | HandBrakeCLI -i "$ITEM" -o "$OUTPUT" --preset="$PRESET" 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3- | grep -i "error"

However, all this will do it print the relevant line from stderr to the screen. It's not clear to me how I can then use this to execute a specific commands e.g. kill HandBrakeCLI ; echo $ITEM >> err.log
I've tried using grep -q to test for a successful match like this:
echo "" | HandBrakeCLI -i "$ITEM" -o "$OUTPUT" --preset="$PRESET" $OPTS 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3- | grep -q "error" && echo "error found" ; echo $ITEM >> failed.txt

But the script simply exits upon encountering the error without moving to the next item in the loop.
Any help appreciated!
updated to answer terdon's query:
I was also curious about the initial echo "" | in the invocation of HandBrake. It was in the original script referenced at the top of the query, but it's not clear to me why it is needed either. I'm running this on MacOS. The full script is
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE=$1
ENCODER=$2
OPTS=$3

TOTAL=$(find "$SOURCE" \! -name ".*" -type f | wc -l)
CURR=0
DESTINATION="PROCESSED"

ENCODER=${ENCODER:="hw"}

# Create directorys
[[ -d $DESTINATION ]] || mkdir -p $DESTINATION

while IFS= read -d '' -r ITEM
do
  RES=`ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of default=nw=1 "$ITEM" | grep 'height*' | cut -c 8-`
  FILE=${ITEM##*/}
  EXT=${ITEM##*.}
  EXT=$(echo $EXT | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]")
  OUTPUT="$DESTINATION/${FILE%.*}.$EXT"

  # Get the right preset
  if [[ "$RES" == "2160" ]] && [[ "$ENCODER" == "hw" ]]
  then
    PRESET="H.265 Apple VideoToolbox 2160p 4K"
  elif [[ "$RES" == "2160" ]] && [[ "$ENCODER" == "sw" ]]
    then
      PRESET="Fast 2160p60 4K HEVC"
  elif [[ "$RES" != "2160" ]] && [[ "$ENCODER" == "hw" ]]
    then
      PRESET="H.265 Apple VideoToolbox 1080p"
  elif [[ "$RES" != "2160" ]] && [[ "$ENCODER" == "sw" ]]
    then
      PRESET="Fast 1080p30"
    fi
  
  echo "Processing" $FILE "using preset" $PRESET
  echo "" | HandBrakeCLI -i "$ITEM" -o "$OUTPUT" --preset="$PRESET" $OPTS 2> /dev/null

  CURR=$((CURR + 1))
  echo "done" $CURR "of"$TOTAL
    
done< <(find "$SOURCE" \( -iname '*.mp4' -or -iname '*.mov'  -or -iname '*.MP4' -or -iname '*.MOV' \) -print0)

Update 061224
Following markp-fuso's suggestion, I modified the line calling HandBrake as follows:
echo "" | HandBrakeCLI -i "$ITEM" -o "$OUTPUT" --preset="$PRESET" 2> >(grep -i error && { pkill HandBrakeCLI ; echo $ITEM >> err.log; })

This prints the relevant error to stdout when encountered, but only executes the second part (e.g. killing the process and logging the result) when the current encode is finished. If the encoding simply hangs and keeps spitting out the same error, the second part of the command is not executed. If I change the line to:
echo "" | HandBrakeCLI -i "$ITEM" -o "$OUTPUT" --preset="$PRESET" 2> >(grep -q error && { pkill HandBrakeCLI ; echo $ITEM >> err.log; })

So the grep command exits on encountering the error, the whole script exits without processing any more items in the loop. Oddly though, if I kill the HandBrake process from another shell when the encode hangs, it will then correctly move onto the next item.

What is the point of the echo "" | being piped into HandBrake? Is that needed? And what operating system are you using? Can you show us the actual script you are using? Just add it to the question and use the {} button to format it as code.

Re: """I was also curious about the initial echo "" | in the invocation of HandBrake. It was in the original script referenced at the top of the query, but it's not clear to me why it is needed either.""" Do not use scripts, you do not fully understand. Not all is gold that glitters.

wouldn't echo "" | serve the same purpose as < /dev/null, ie, keep the main program (handbrake in this case) from hanging on, or eating from, stdin?

perhaps something like 2> >(grep -i error && { pkill HandBrakeCLI ; echo $ITEM >> err.log; })

Interesting. I've tried the suggestion from markp-fuso - It partially works. The stderr error is written to the screen and the offending file is written to err.log but the HandBrake process is not killed. I've checked the process names and running pkill HandBrakeCLI from the terminal works, but not when called from the script.

Based on markp-fuso's answer I altered the HandBrake invocation line to:
echo "" | HandBrakeCLI -i "$ITEM" -o "$OUTPUT" --preset="$PRESET" 2> >(grep -q error && { pkill HandBrakeCLI ; echo $ITEM >> err.log; })

There were additional lines in the script that required successful completion of the encoding, so I made this conditional on successful encoding (i.e. error condition not met). Once removed, the script worked as expected.
